# what can be said about stabilizer codes derived by combining stabilizers and logicals

Tags: error-correction, stabilizer-code

Let $C$ be an $[[n,k]]$ stabilizer code with stabilizers $(S_1,\cdots,S_m)$ and logicals $(\bar Z_1,\cdots,\bar Z_k)$ and $(\bar X_1,\cdots,\bar X_k)$. Let's also assume that the destabilizers $(D_1,\cdots,D_m)$ have been calculated. I can build a new $[[n,k-1]]$ code $C^-$ by taking one of the logicals and treating it as a new stabilizer; so the stabilizers of $C^-$ are $(S_1,\cdots,S_m,\bar Z_1)$; the corresponding logical $\bar X_1$ becomes a destabilizer. Going the other way I can build a new $[[n,k+1]]$ code $C^+$ by treating one of the stabilizers as a logical;
the corresponding destabilizer also becomes a logical. So $C^+$ has $(S_1,\cdots,S_{m-1})$ as stabilizers and logicals $(\bar Z_1,\cdots,\bar Z_k,S_m)$ and $(\bar X_1,\cdots,\bar X_k,D_m)$.

What can be said about $C^-$ and $C^+$ in relation to $C$?. Some properties are obvious : basis elements of $C$ get merged for $C^-$ and split for $C^+$. Can anything be said about distance?
weight distribution...